# How can I make my 1MB home page load faster?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, gzip, page-load-time

My home page is 1MB. For users with a 56k modem, that is enormous. My Home Page site from 500k have also used jquery.

What can I do to make the page load faster? Can I cache the ISP I use, and would that be useful?

EDIT

How can use gzip in asp.net?

Which type of cache is useful for web pages?

Comment: Could you give us a better break down of the resources on the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable gzip compression, minify HTML, ... follow [YSlow recommendadtions](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html). You could also send a *light* version of the page immediately and then load some parts using AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [lazy loading](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/102/Lazy-Loading-jQuery-Tabs-with-ASP.NET) pattern, it means that you load content not the first time but on demand

Comment: what is lazy loading pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You might like watching ["Improving ASP.NET MVC Application Performance"](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/02/22/mvcconf-videos-available.aspx) by Steven Smith.

Answer (score 1):

1MB is fairly chunky. You either have a LOT of third party libraries, widgets and so on, or there's some media files like images responsible. Take a look at the images you have in the page: a reasonably high-quality jpeg 800 x 600 should only be around 50k.

Answer (score 0):

1MB is a lot for a home page particularly if you are expecting to have users coming over a 56k modem. I would start by reducing the size of your home page.